# Mistake in old granted UK visa, realized while applying for a new one

Tags: visas, uk

I made a mistake in one of my parents' date of birth during a visitor visa application which was granted. Now I'm going to apply for a Tier-2 visa and realized the mistake while reviewing the old form of the visitor visa. I'm a non-EU person residing in EU and applying from EU. How to amend the previously submitted mistake?

Comment: I Would enter the correct DOB this time and make a note in the Additional information section and would try to not invite unnecessary attention

Answer (score 10):

You recorded your parent's birth date incorrectly in a previous application and discovered the error in preparing a T2 application.  They know that people make clerical errors and they will be reasonable about if several hurdles are cleared...

- Does the applicant, *at face value*, appear to be bona fide?
- Would the ECO have reached a different conclusion if he had access to
  the correct information?
- This is a *big, big one*: was (or is) the applicant in a position to
  know the correct information?
- Has there been an obvious attempt to conceal something?
- Does the error invalidate any of the evidence submitted (previously
  or now)?

I assume most of your answers are 'no' or 'not applicable'. Lots of stuff we see here are cases where items 1 and 2 fail and that leads to more difficulty in clearing items 3 and 4.

Some applicants do not know who their parents are and lots more of them don't know their birth dates. As long as your parent is not notorious in some way that would affect item 4, I would offer something along the lines of...

> In completing this application I had access to more authoritative
>   materials than when I applied in 2014. Accordingly, my father's birth
>   date has been recorded correctly in this application.

or...

> Because of its importance I had this application double-checked
>   against source and this resulted in a correction to my father's birth
>   date. The correct value has been recorded on this form.

...or any other similar statement. Note that these statements are free from apologies or lengthy digressions, and above all they do not tell the ECO what to think (they do not like that).

---

Note: Sometimes a question will come up asking if an applicant should persist an error made in an earlier application. Their rationale is that it's more convenient if everything sync's up. But the answer is emphatically **no**, never persist a previous error. It fails on item 3.